# How to convert TTF font for use in three.js

Tags: fonts, three.js, truetype

I am looking for a library that will convert a ttf or otf font to a js font.

I am aware of this converter tool http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html

However I would like to know how this site is making the conversion. So I can implement the conversions of the font files myself.

Ideally I am looking for a JS or PHP library to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter from `typeface.js` uses **server-side perl scripts** and [the sources are on Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~davidchester/typeface.js/trunk/files/head:/perl/).

Here is an extract from its [README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~davidchester/typeface.js/trunk/view/head:/perl/README):

```
 use TypefaceJS;

 my $typeface = TypefaceJS::new->( input_filename => "truetype_font.ttf",
 unicode_range_names => ['Basic Latin', 'Latin-1 Supplement'], );

 $typeface->write_file( output_filename => 'font.typeface.js' );
```

Comment: Thank you, are you aware of a JS or PHP library capable of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: No, I never encountered a JS or PHP port of this converter

Answer (score -1):

This does it I think https://github.com/gero3/facetype.js main website at http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Nevertheless, this is the correct answer - the OP asked for a tool to do the font conversion, this is that tool.  What's the point in adding words just to pad it out?

Comment: I didn’t notice the question was asking for a library; my mistake.  However, for future reference, 1) when linking to a library, it’s best to provide a demonstration of how to solve the problem using the library, and 2) library-recommendation questions such as this one should be closed as off-topic rather than answered.